# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on') to connect metamask in React

Tags: reactjs, react-component, metamask

I am trying to connect the metamask wallet into my project but there is no metamask extention whe website give error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')**. So I am doing basic if else command which is:

```
const connectWalletHandler = () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

And in render:

```
{connectWalletHandler ? <Wallet /> : <div>Metamask extention is needed</div>}
```

But still I get the same error. So how can I control the wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `{connectWalletHandler ? ...}` into `{connectWalletHandler() ? ...}`